# Is there a way to execute spreadsheets.values.update without OAuth authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm making a discord bot that will be open to the public to use, and it will work by updating a google spreadsheet with values given in a command.  Unfortunately, from what I see in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)'s "Try this API" feature, I can only use Google OAuth v2.  Using an API key as a form of authentication gives me the error: `Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project`.  How can I make it so that a user doesn't need to sign in for this to work?

This is the code:

```
  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/sheets/v4/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      "spreadsheetId": "1AFCiplLlZRdO5Phb4DUh8M8sKKnUimJftVDGH9UAA3M",
      "range": "Ratings!H2",
      "valueInputOption": "RAW",
      "resource": {
        "values": [
          [
            7.5
          ]
        ]
      }
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: YOUR_CLIENT_ID});
  });
```

Thank you if you can help me, this has been stumping me for a while now.
spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFCiplLlZRdO5Phb4DUh8M8sKKnUimJftVDGH9UAA3M/edit#gid=569426832

Comment: Making the sheet public/Anyone with link can edit is one option.

Comment: @I'-'I added the link

Comment: What I meant is You can access the sheet without OAuth, if the sheet in question is public. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing But why do you want to avoid oAuth?

Comment: @I'-'I because I want it to be so that someone can just use the bot without signing in.  For example, they might want to rate a full album, and wouldn't want to sign in using OAuth every time they use the command.

Comment: @I'-'I It does not work when it is publically editable.

Comment: Doesn't work is not a valid Problem description. It should work. How are you calling the api with api keys? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/README.md#using-api-keys

Comment: @I'-'I I'm using the "Try this API" feature using a demo API key.  It gave me the same error as before.

Comment: I'm guessing you need a real API key. `get` works with demo API key